# Can you bridge and jump inside gated complexes?

Tags: eve-online

Capital ships can jump to a cyno, and Titans and Blac Ops ships can bridge other ships to a cyno. I'm wondering how that works inside complexes behind an acceleration gate.

Gated complexes are e.g. missions or faction warfare complexes. I know that they restrict warping in their vicinity, you always end up at the gate itself instead of your intended target.

How does jumping to a cyno inside a complex work? Is there any difference between a ship jumping itself or bridging other ships? Or is it just not possible to jump inside a complex?

The idea would be to target mission runners in expensive ships and jump a recon/bomber fleet on them using a Black Ops bridge to a covert cyno. Is that possible inside a mission?

Comment: While, not a complete answer, I have encountered at least one mission where I was able to warp my salvage character directly to my mission runner character, despite my mission runner having to traverse gates to get there.  ([Dread Pirate Scarlet](http://eve-survival.org/wikka.php?wakka=DreadPirateScarlet4))  My point is: not all acceleration gates work the same, apparently.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless they changed it recently, no, you should not be able to bridge directly into a deadspace area. [This](http://community.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=685400) thread seems to agree, though it is a few years back. [This](http://community.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=1567438) and [this](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=52439) thread seems to agree, and they're more recent.

A good place to check is Singularity, the public test server. Get a friend ( or an alt ), procure a blops/titan/etc. and test it out. Should be simple enough ( remember, everything is ~100 ISK on Singularity ).